# How can I sort a dictionary by key while ignoring case?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, hash

I use the following code to sort my dictionary:

```
meaningHash = {'Banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit'}
sortedMeaningHash = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(meaningHash.items()))
print sortedMeaningHash
```

The result is:

```
OrderedDict([('Banana', 'fruit'), ('apple', 'fruit')])
```

And the desired output is:

```
OrderedDict([('apple', 'fruit'), ('Banana', 'fruit')])
```

Comment: use sorted `key` argument... will post answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the `key` argument to `sorted` to sort by lower case:

```
def check_lower(pair):
    key,value = pair
    return (key.lower(),value)

meaningHash={'Banana':'fruit','apple':'fruit'}

sortedMeaningHash = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(meaningHash.items(),
                                                    key=check_lower))
print(sortedMeaningHash)
```

the `key` is a callable that returns the representation that each item should be sorted by. so it takes the item pair for each element of the dict and calls `.lower()` on the key.

Answer (score 4):

Add a key arg to the `sorted` call:

```
sortedMeaningHash = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(meaningHash.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()))
```

Comment: if there is a key with both lower and upper case then the dictionary should sort by the value but you throw away the value in your lambda expression.